# How do I make a variable in my class global but only make it global within the class?

Tags: python, class, variables, global

I want to make it so x is only global within the class.

I have tried using self.x but that does not seem to work. I could be doing it wrong though.

```
class Test:

   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def test1(self,number):
      global x
      x = number
      print(x)

   def whereIwantToRedefineIt(self):
      print(x)


Test().test1(2) #<------ Making output 2

x=200 #<-------------- It should not be able to redefine the variable

Test().whereIwantToRedefineIt() #<-------- I want to make this output 2
```

I want to make the function "whereIwantToRedefineIt" not be affected by the "x=200" which is outside the class. I want it to output 2

Comment: "only make it global within the class" Then it isn't global.

Comment: You're using an anti-pattern by declaring global within a class method anyway. Define as a class variable would be a start, but I don't know the ultimate goal.

Comment: Call it something else, like `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test:

  def __init__(self):
      self.x = None
  def test1(self,number):
      self.x = number
      print(x)

   def whereIwantToRedefineIt(self):
      print(self.x)
```

You can get the desired result if you invoke the methods on the same instance.

```
test = Test()
test.test1(2)
test.whereIwantToRedefineIt() # This will print 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is a [class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible), which can be accessed by prefixing the variable name with the class name:

```
class MyClass:
    somevar = 0
    def somemethod(self):
        print(MyClass.somevar)
```